# How to reuse a predefined line style in matplotlib.pyplot.plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

First, I defined a line through `matplotlib.lines.Line2D`:

```
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
newLine = mlines.Line2D([], [], color="blue", linestyle='-',linewidth=2)
```

(For simplicity) In the same script file, I would like to call these line settings whenever possible through: `matplotlib.pyplot.plot` **without repeating the kwargs**, such as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dataXaxis=np.arange(0,10)
dataYaxis=np.arange(5,15)

plt.plot(dataXaxis, dataYaxis, <CALL newLine PROPERTIES>)
```

instead of:

```
plt.plot(dataXaxis, dataYaxis, color="blue", linestyle='-',linewidth=2)
```

**Context:**

I might be confused with the above functionalities. Yet I want to use predefined line style settings associated to a *predefined concept*. For instance, I want to use a particular line style whenever I plot 'input vs. time' relation, and another particular style to plot 'output vs. time' relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just define a dictionary with the keyword arguments that you want to use each time, e.g.,

```
newlinestyle = {'color': 'blue', 'linestyle': '-', 'linewidth': 2}

plt.plot(dataXaxis, dataYaxis, **newlinestyle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Matt Pitkin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47432510/3393574)'s answer, I tried to generalize the approach as a MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

newlinestyles = {'dict1': {'color': 'blue', 'linestyle': '-', 'linewidth': 2},
                 'dict2': {'color': 'red' , 'linestyle': '-', 'linewidth': 2} }

dataXaxis=np.arange(0,10)
dataYaxis=np.arange(5,15)

plt.plot(dataXaxis, dataYaxis, **newlinestyles['dict1'])
plt.show()

plt.plot(dataXaxis, dataYaxis, **newlinestyles['dict2'])

plt.close()
```